# Chrome extension: Clicking a button every X seconds

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, timer, click

I am super new to chrome extension development, but I do have some quite basic JS knowledge. I am trying to make this extension where for a specific site I would have a browser action (preferably two : START and STOP). I would click a browser action (START) and a script would start that would repeatedly click one button for example every 1 or 2 minutes. Then I could click the STOP browser action to stop it.

Can anyone maybe guide me to the right direction how to do this because the whole idea of chrome message parsing and foreground/background scripts is a bit confusing to me. Also what's the best way of running a code that is repeating like this for this particular case?

Thanks a lot I appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: you can do a setInterval and then trigger a click

Comment: Yeah , but I'm not exactly sure what part of the code should I have in my background script and what part should be in the content scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon can be added with [pageAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) API (an icon inside the address box) or [browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) API (an icon on the toolbar). See sample extensions to get the feel how the API may be used: [pageAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:pageaction), [browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:browseraction).

As you can see from the samples both these APIs are used from the background script. To manipulate the active page DOM just inject a content script file/code with [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) which will then click the button.

Here's a very basic example for browserAction without using messages because we simply can check whether our `interval` variable was already defined by the previous injection. The injected content script runs in its own "isolated world" so you don't have to worry about conflicts with page scripts or variables.

- manifest.json

  ```
  {
      "name": "Start/stop",
      "version": "1.0",
      "permissions": ["activeTab"],
      "background": {
          "scripts": ["background.js"],
          "persistent": false
      },
      "browser_action": {
          "default_title": "Start me",
          "default_icon": {
              "19": "icon-start-19x19.png",
              "38": "icon-start-38x38.png"
          },
      },
      "manifest_version": 2
  }
  ```
- background.js, simple version:

  ```
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "content.js"});
  });
  ```
- background.js, advanced version, changes the icon accordingly and independently for each tab:

  ```
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
      chrome.browserAction.getTitle({tabId: tab.id}, function(title) {
          var newTitle, newIcon;
          if (title.indexOf("Start") == 0) {
              newTitle = "Stop me";  newIcon = "stop";
          else {
              newTitle = "Start me"; newIcon = "start";
          }
          chrome.browserAction.setTitle({tabId: tab.id, title: newTitle});
          chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
              tabId: tab.id,
              path: {
                  19: "icon-"+newIcon+"-19x19.png",
                  38: "icon-"+newIcon+"-38x38.png"
              }
          });
          chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "content.js"});
      });
  });
  ```
- content.js:

  ```
  if (interval) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = 0;
  } else {
      var btn = document.querySelector("button.something");
      if (btn) {
          var interval = setInterval(function() {
              btn.click();
          }, 60 * 1000);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Oh that sounds awesome. Thank yoy very much. I'll try it out when I'll get the chance :)

Comment: I just tested it within my use-case and it works perfectly and the icon/title changing is super cool and useful for me ! Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delay. I tested it an it works great.
However:

I was trying to do this with a PageAction instead of BrowserAction. I managed to set it up so the pageaction is only visible at the site I want, but the button I'm clicking also involves a sort of a refresh of the site which stops the interval. Any ideas how should I tackle this ? Or should I make a new thread ?

Comment: @Near, refreshing the page reloads the content script as well so of course the timers are destroyed too. I'm pretty sure there was a duplicate question/answer for the timer-based action recently on stackoverflow, can't find it now... Basically you'll need to use setInterval inside the background page script and send a message to the content script in the timer function.

Comment: Oh ok. Just to be sure, I move the interval if-else logic to the background script and in the callback , instead of clicking the button I will send a message and then on the receiving end ( content script ) the message should trigger the button click right ?And does my background script have to be persistent in this case? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yes, either persistent or you'll have to use [alarms API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms)